# Remove Adjacent Space near a Special Character using regex

Tags: c#, regex, string

Using regex want to remove adjacent Space near replacement Character

```cs
replacementCharcter = '-'


this._adjacentSpace = new Regex($@"\s*([\{replacementCharacter}])\s*");
MatchCollection replaceCharacterMatch = this._adjacentSpace.Matches(extractedText);
foreach (Match replaceCharacter in replaceCharacterMatch)
{
    if (replaceCharacter.Success)
    {
        cleanedText = Extactedtext.Replace(replaceCharacter.Value, replaceCharacter.Value.Trim());
    }
}


Extractedtext = - whi, - ch

cleanedtext = -whi, -ch
```

expected result : cleanedtext = -whi,-ch

Comment: If you weren't aware, you can scroll down on the "ask a question" screen and see a preview of what your question will look like when posted. That way you can see what formatting problems your question might have before you post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```cs
var Extactedtext = "- whi, - ch";
var replacementCharacter = "-";
var _adjacentSpace = new Regex($@"\s*({Regex.Escape(replacementCharacter)})\s*");
var cleanedText = _adjacentSpace.Replace(Extactedtext, "$1");
Console.WriteLine(cleanedText); // => -whi,-ch
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/k64kKP).

**NOTE**:

- `replacementCharacter` is of type `string` in the code above
- `$@"\s*({Regex.Escape(replacementCharacter)})\s*"` will create a regex like `\s*-\s*`, `Regex.Escape()` will escape any regex-special char (like `+`, `(`, etc.) correctly to be used in a regex pattern, and the whole regex simply matches (and captured into Group 1 with the capturing parentheses) the `replacementCharacter` enclosed with zero or more whitespaces
- No need using `Regex.Matches`, just replace all matches if there are any, that is how `Regex.Replace` works.
- `_adjacentSpace` is the compiled `Regex` object, to replace, just call the `.Replace()` method of the regex object instance
- The replacement is a backreference to the Group 1 value, the `-` char here.